# how to get total sum of filtered data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, where-clause

I am new to php, mysql.

I use four columns, `companyname`, `issuedwt`, `receiptwt` & `workloss` in my database.

I use below query to get total of issuedwt, receiptwt & workloss.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(issuedwt) AS IssuedTotal, SUM(receiptwt) AS ReceiptTotal, SUM(workloss) AS Balance FROM `worksheet`")
or die(mysql_error());
```

I want to use filter option based on `companyname`.(i.e. company1, company2, company3)

If i filter `company1`, I need total of only `company1`. What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply filter on the `companyname` with `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  
  SUM(issuedwt) AS IssuedTotal, 
  SUM(receiptwt) AS ReceiptTotal,
  SUM(workloss) AS Balance 
FROM `worksheet`
WHERE compamnyname = 'company1' -- for example
```

This will give you `IssuedTotal`, `ReceiptTotal`, and `Balance` for only the `company1`.

---

However, if you want to get a list of `companyname`s and the totals, use a `GROUP BY companyname`, but you still can filter on the companyname:

```
SELECT companyname, 
  SUM(issuedwt) AS IssuedTotal, 
  SUM(receiptwt) AS ReceiptTotal, 
  SUM(workloss) AS Balance 
FROM `worksheet`
GROUP BY companyname
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the "group by" option in your query will let mysql know which elements belong together, and it will calculate the sums per group:

```
"SELECT 
  SUM(issuedwt) AS IssuedTotal, 
  SUM(receiptwt) AS ReceiptTotal, 
  SUM(workloss) AS Balance 
  FROM worksheet 
  group by companyname"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

You can always limit which companies are shown using the 'where' option, (select from TABLE where COLUMN = VALUE) but I am assuming you want to get the data for each and every company; then just use the group by.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(issuedwt) AS IssuedTotal, SUM(receiptwt) AS ReceiptTotal, 
       SUM(workloss) AS Balance 
FROM `worksheet`
WHERE companyname = 'company1';
```

If you want company wise data than use below query:

```
SELECT companyname, SUM(issuedwt) AS IssuedTotal, SUM(receiptwt) AS ReceiptTotal, 
       SUM(workloss) AS Balance 
FROM `worksheet`
GROUP BY companyname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause along with your query:

```
SELECT companyname, SUM(issuedwt) AS IssuedTotal, SUM(receiptwt) AS ReceiptTotal,
SUM(workloss) AS Balance FROM `worksheet`
GROUP BY companyname
```